# ggplot2: using different linetypes for different series of the same group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found many similar answers, but i couldn't relate them to my example. Please point me to the correct post if it already exists. In this example I have three different genes from two different replicates (called Series).

I am trying to plot each gene in the same color but with different line types, and combined with points. This code almost works if I skip `geom_line()`. But I don't understand the error message:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
combined %>% 
  ggplot(combined, aes(x=Time, y=Count)) +
  geom_point(data=combined %>% 
               filter(str_detect(gene, "asmbl")), aes(color=Series)) +
  geom_line(data=combined %>% 
              filter(str_detect(gene, "asmbl")), aes(color=Series, group=Series)) +
  geom_point(data=combined %>% 
               filter(str_detect(gene, "Sarc4_g23851T")), aes(color=gene)) +
  geom_point(data=combined %>% 
               filter(str_detect(gene, "Sarc4_g23850T")), aes(color=gene))
```

Data:

```
combined <- structure(list(gene = c("align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", 
"align_id:186820|asmbl_31839", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", 
"Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", 
"Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", 
"Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", 
"Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23851T", 
"Sarc4_g23851T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", 
"Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", 
"Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", 
"Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", 
"Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T", "Sarc4_g23850T"
), Time = c("12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "42", "48", "54", "60", 
"66", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "42", "54", "60", "66", "12", 
"18", "24", "30", "36", "42", "48", "54", "60", "66", "12", "18", 
"24", "30", "36", "42", "54", "60", "66", "12", "18", "24", "30", 
"36", "42", "48", "54", "60", "66", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", 
"42", "54", "60", "66"), Count = c(36.5856, 29.1905, 9.5834, 
18.1533, 15.9757, 141.075, 164.396, 286.494, 313.51, 297.194, 
31.524, 22.48, 22.8498, 13.5205, 55.9709, 229.88, 401.08, 533.74, 
584.868, 23.6579, 28.139, 28.0263, 30.5701, 33.4486, 33.3998, 
33.2913, 29.0451, 26.0574, 22.2455, 24.2018, 22.9098, 28.4843, 
27.5675, 26.5617, 24.9472, 27.3172, 22.1812, 19.7493, 7.02732, 
7.83637, 5.9542, 5.6151, 7.51841, 7.36599, 7.39079, 6.70167, 
4.81567, 3.46868, 7.14292, 5.1345, 5.30578, 5.16931, 4.71502, 
5.60258, 5.87787, 4.24783, 3.81306), Series = c("BT", "BT", "BT", 
"BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", 
"CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", 
"BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", 
"CT", "CT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", "BT", 
"BT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT")), row.names = c(NA, 
-57L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: So you want to map colour to gene and series to linetype?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be correct. I tried different combinations of color and group, but that was without linetype.

Comment: Like this? `ggplot(combined, aes(x = Time, y = Count, colour = gene, linetype = Series, group = interaction(gene, Series))) + geom_line() + geom_point()`

Comment: Exactly! I see I need to learn a new function, interaction()... 
Thanks a lot!